# How to search list of elements in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i mean i need desired output_dataframe and specific_indexes of Original_dataframe from search_list? How to do that? by fastest way?

Original_dataframe:

```
   textA  TextB
0       a        zz
1       bbb        zzzzz
2       ccc        zzz
```

search list:

```
search_list = ['a','ccc']
```

i mean i need desired output_dataframe AND specific_indexes of Original_dataframe from search_list

Desired output_dataframe:

```
   textA  TextB
0       a        zz
2       ccc        zzz
```

Desired output specific_indexes:

```
specific_indexes [0, 2]
```

> Computation time is most important.

Comment: use `df[df['textA'].isin(search_list)].index`

Comment: Do yo uneed check any column? Or ony first column?

Comment: @jezrael need to check in column textA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need check any column use for index use:

```
idx = df.index[df.isin(search_list).any(axis=1)]

df1 = df[df.isin(search_list).any(axis=1)]
```

For check one column by better performance filter indices:

```
idx = df.index[df['textA'].isin(search_list)]

df1 = df[df['textA'].isin(search_list)]
```

Comment: I seriously don't understand your logic on duplicates, IMO this is one (just a very basic check here and not necessarily worthy of answering in full)… NB. I didn't DV

Comment: @mozway - yop, still not understand? Dupe -> wiki.

Comment: Because I considered it **not** a duplicate in good faith, there is no absolute *right* or *wrong*, we are human beings (well, I am) and can have different opinions

Comment: @mozway - ya, I answer it too in good faith. But after realise it is dupe, no rep hunting, but wiki. So no points...

Comment: I don't blame you for that, but please be aware that your behavior is quite stressful, you really jump at people within minutes, nothing is perfect

Comment: @jezrael guys i also need to know output_dataframe

Comment: @mozway - I have absolutely no problem with answer, but if it is dupe, why rep hunting? Tis is what I dont like.

Comment: @BoldGanbaatar - added to answer.